# I can't send an email using form in access because I have added cc function. How i resolve it?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I included the cc function in my code and it works. I am able to send an email and cc someone else. However, I am unable to send an email without filling in the cc field. The email only works when I fill in the "To" and "CC" field. How do I resolve this?

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim fileDiag As FileDialog
    Dim file As Variant

    Set fileDiag = FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fileDiag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If fileDiag.Show Then
        For Each file In fileDiag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtAttachment = file
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click()
    Me.txtBody = Null
    Me.txtSubject = Null
    Me.txtTo = Null
    Me.txtAttachment = Null
    Me.txtCC = Null

End Sub

Private Sub btnHome_Click()
    DoCmd.BrowseTo 2, "HomePageMainFrm"
End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click()
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oEmail As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    oEmail.To = Me.txtTo.Value
    oEmail.Subject = Me.txtSubject.Value
    oEmail.CC Me.txtCC.Value
    oEmail.Body = Me.txtBody.Value
    If Len(Me.txtAttachment) > 0 Then
        oEmail.Attachments.Add Me.txtAttachment.Value
    End If
    With oEmail
        If Not IsNull(.To) And Not IsNull(.Subject) And Not IsNull(.Body) And Not IsNull(.CC) Then
            .Send
            MsgBox "Email Sent!"
        Else
            MsgBox "Please fill out the required fields."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You say in your code that CC can't be null. So adapt your code. Don't know why you'd want to check whether CC is not null so can't suggest what you should do.

Comment: Why is there no = sign in `oEmail.CC Me.txtCC.Value`? So if field is null, the code doesn't work? Try wrapping in Nz() function `Nz(Me.txtCC, "")`. Don't need to type `.Value` because it is default.

Comment: Hi thanks, Nz(Me.txtCC, "") helped!

Answer (score 0):

The [`CC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.cc) property of a [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object is a string-valued property whose value will be an empty string (`""`) if no recipients are cc'ed - this property should not be null.

You can easily resolve this issue in your code using the [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function, which will return an alternative value if the supplied argument is null:

```
oEmail.CC = Nz(Me.txtCC.Value, "")
```

However, as noted in the MS VBA documentation linked above, the [`CC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.cc) property merely contains a semi-colon delimited list of display names - you should instead modify the contents of the [`Recipients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection when adding recipients (independent of the recipient type) to a [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) object.

Adding an item to the [`Recipients`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection using the [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method will yield a [`Recipient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient) object, which has a [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) property which may be used to designate the recipient as a cc by setting the property to [`olCC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype) (or `2` if using late binding).